# Units of the Stokes-Einstein rotational diffusion coefficient

Tags: units, dimensional-analysis, diffusion

The [Stokes-Einstein rotational diffusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_relation_%28kinetic_theory%29#Stokes-Einstein_equation) relation tells us that we can write down a rotational diffusion coefficient for a sphere as:

$$D_r \approx \frac{k_B T}{\zeta_f} \approx \frac{k_B T}{(8 \pi \eta)(r)^3}$$

Where $k_B$ is Boltzmann's constant, $T$ is the temperature in Kelvin, $\zeta_f \approx (8 \pi \eta)(r)^3$ is the friction, $\eta$ is the viscosity of the medium (e.g. $\approx 1 \space cP$ in pure water), and $r$ is the radius of the sphere.

For an example calculation of $D_r \approx 0.2 \space rad^2/s$ (or $Hz$) of a $\approx 1 \space \mu m$ radius sphere in pure water at room temperature, please [see this site](http://www.microurl.info/YOtwp) (this shortened URL is going to WolframAlpha).

However, as we can directly see in the calculation, the units for $D_r$ are clearly expressible as rad/s or Hz.  Why are the units for $D_r$ always reported as rad$^2$/s in the literature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The diffusion equation takes the form
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=D\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}
$$
where $f$ is some function. For simplicity, let's let $f=\rho$ the mass-density. In this case, then we have, units-wise,
$$
\frac{{\rm kg/m^3}}{\rm s} = \left[D\right]\frac{\rm kg/m^3}{\rm m^2}
$$
Thus, in order to have the correct units on both sides, $\left[D\right]={\rm m^2/s}$. In the case of [rotational diffusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotational_diffusion), the diffusion equation takes the form
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=D_r\frac{1}{\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left(\sin\theta\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}\right)+D_r\frac{1}{\sin^2\theta}\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial\phi^2}
$$
Since $\theta$ and $\phi$ are measured in radians and $\sin\theta$ is unitless, then we must have that $\left[D_r\right]={\rm rad^2/s}$.

Answer (score 1):

A rotational diffusion constant has units of $1/s$. Radians are dimensionless numbers and can not be included in a formal dimensional analysis.

The link to your calculation is broken, but here's mine (probably the same):

$k_B T$ is an energy $[kg m^2/s^2]$, $\eta$ is dynamic viscosity $[kg/ms]$. Thus

$$
\mathcal D_r \propto \frac{k_B T}{\eta r^3} \mathrm{~has~units~} [\frac{kg m^2}{s^2}\frac{ms}{kg m^3}]=[\frac{1}{s}]
$$

Informally, we may think of a diffusion constant as a mean squared displacement divided by a time. And since the variable displaced is an angle, the diffusion constant is often written $\mathrm{rad}^2/s$. However, a radian is [defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian#Definition) as a length divided by another length, and is therefore indistinguishable from $1$ in a dimensional analysis.