# Expression for "rotational diffusivity"; orientation random-walk of thin rod-like particles?

Tags: diffusion

From [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/439661/83380) and from the [Stokes-Einstein equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_relation_(kinetic_theory)#Stokes-Einstein_equation) the diffusivity of a particle of radius $R$ in a fluid of viscosity $\eta$ is

$$D=\frac{k_B T}{6 \pi \eta R}$$

where $\xi=6 \pi \eta R$ is a coefficient of friction [Stokes' law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_law) such that for velocity $v$ the viscous drag force is

$$F_D=\xi v.$$

The diffusion in 1 dimension would then be given as

$$\langle x^2\rangle = 2Dt. $$

As suggested in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/468202/83380) to that question, the diffusivity is usually so strongly limited by the drag force that it does not depend much on the density of the particle.

**Question:** Is there an *orientation analog* to the positional diffusion? For example, if the particle were a long thin rod, would the direction of its axis move in a random-walk type process? If so, is there an analogous orientation diffusivity, perhaps something like $D_{rot}$ where $\langle\theta^2\rangle = 2D_{rot}t$ based on the length of the thin rod and likewise independent of particle density?

**update:** As [pointed out](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/470027/is-there-an-expression-for-rotational-diffusivity-an-orientation-analog-to-th#comment1056751_470027) by @KyleKanos there is indeed the concept of "rotational diffusivity". [This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/99560/83380) mentions that for a *spherical particle*:

$$D_{rot} \approx \frac{k_B T}{\zeta_f} \approx \frac{k_B T}{(8 \pi \eta)(r)^3}$$

and @KyleKanos's [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/99563/83380) begins to describe how it can be used.

What I'm looking for here instead is $D_{rot}$ for a long thin rod.

Comment: The diffusion coefficient is generally a rank-2 tensor. I also mention rotational analog [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/99563/25301).

Comment: @KyleKanos thanks for that! Yes, that expression for $D_r$ in the question (for a spherical particle) is just the kind of thing I'm looking for, except for a thin rod. I'll have a look at expression in your answer, I'm hoping that for small times it will result in something that reduces to $\langle\theta^2\rangle = 2D_{r}t$ or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rotational diffusion was solved by Edwardes / Perrin / Langevin at their times.
It is normally made for particles of Ellipsoid shape, since it is easier to solve analytically. A long and thin ellipsoid is your rod. Try Google "ellipsoid brownian motion".
The model is for macroscopic particles immersed in a viscous fluid, but should work also for long molecules in a gas.

Solution, thin ellipsoid of axis $a$ (roughly equivalent to $2a$ rod) and (small) radius $b$:

$D = \frac{kT}{C_r} $

Where $C_r$ is the friction for the ellipsoid rotating in the fluid; for our thin rod,

$ 
C_r \simeq \frac{16 \pi \eta}{3 P_r}
$

Where again, the $P_r$ is an elliptic integral that represent the particle size, at the moment I don't manage to calculate:

$
P_r = \int ^{\infty} _0 \frac{dx}{(a^2 +x)^{\frac{3}{2}} (b^2 + x) }
$

All this discussion work for orientation the mayor axis of a thin rod (rotation around the two perpendicular axes); if the particle has a stranger shape, I guess we must consider all components and tensors.

Here some paper where the model is discussed in English:
[Paper Wegener et al, A general ellipsoid cannot always ..](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d7d6/080b4fdd95e1071e9c34acc61f769e659e28.pdf)
[Koening, Brownian motion of an ellipsoid](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/bip.1975.360141115)
And the book [The Langevin equation by Coffey](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/8195) has a chapter.
[Wikipedia Perrin friction factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perrin_friction_factors)

Comment: Wow this is wonderful, thank you! I'll give these a read as soon as I can.

Comment: Thanks, is actually messy, please don't rely on my folmulas too much

Comment: That's okay for now, I will check the references and let you know what I find. *Thanks!*

Comment: You may look also at polarization of gases (dipole molecules must align with the electric field, then they relax to random orientation) and at ferrofluids, that do the same with magnetic fields.

Comment: Ah and a lot of physics about polarization of interstellar dust, that being very rarefied has some problems with diffusivity

Comment: slightly related: [What is the physics of the “spinning dust” contribution to Cosmic Microwave Background measurements?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/22602/7982) and also [Has “GHz-spinning dust” ever been demonstrated in the laboratory?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/28760/7982)

Comment: Yes, is where rotational diffusivity is being discussed by physicists today!  I think Lazarian made the best reviews; but you have many more effects there, free electrons, EM waves, radio emission.... . http://www.astro.wisc.edu/~lazarian/

Comment: Sorry again, an old but simple & good description is in the book by Bottcher, "Theory of electric polarization"  par 55 - 56. It is more phenomenological (observed relaxation times in dipole gases)